# events undefined in angular hints console

Tags: angularjs, events, undefined, angularjs-ng-click

I have a big AngularJS project and I am trying to clean it from warnings. But this type of warning appear:

$event is undefined
$event.stopPropagation is undefined
ng-click events are also undefined.

Any idea why this is happening? everything works fine in the app but I got almost 700 hints for it at the browser. I am using chrome if this is relevant.